# Suddenly no more sound on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 20.04, alsa

**TL;DR**

I got the inspiration for the solution from the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/862896/39456, I found this question through the proposed solution by [@laugeo](https://askubuntu.com/users/276751/laugeo): thanks for the hint with the codec, mine wasn't on the list.

**The problem**

Until last week-end I had still sound on my PC. Then after an update: no more sound. 
What is strange though, I booted up the PC yesterday with the *live image of Ubuntu 20.04* and there I have sound!

Since then I tried already the following tips an tricks without success:

- [No sound on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245100/no-sound-on-ubuntu-20-04)
- https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-no-sound-issue-ubuntu
- [(yet another) No sound in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243359/yet-another-no-sound-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Again, booting into the live Ubuntu 20.04 gives me sound, booting from hard drive gives nothing.

What else I tried was to plug the speakers into the screen (HDMI), but still silence. Although the parameters window for the speaker shows that there is sound played, just not for real.

Here's my setup:

```sh
lspci |grep 'Audio'
1d:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590]
1f:00.3 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller
```

Has anyone any idea how I can get the sound back? Because, as mentioned, the **sound was there** until last week-end.

**The solution**

In `pavucontrol` under the **Configuration** tab I changed the **Profile** for my sound card to *Analog Stereo Duplex* and then under the **Output** tab I switched the port to the right one. Sound is back!

Comment: look 1st answer  here :   https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243359/yet-another-no-sound-in-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: @laugeo unfortunately nope, didn't work either

Comment: do you see all faders   in alsamixer  ? or  do you need to press F6 and select 2nd sound device to see them ?

Comment: @laugeo Yes, every time i launch alsamixer I do indeed see first the HDMI output and I have to switch with F6 to the generic one (which I "use")

Answer (score 2):

Various checks:

- In pavucontrol , does vumeter move when playing   ? As your sound device is the 2nd one (as seen in alsamixer) ,  I suppose you know that you must select it as default in devices tab with green button .
- After that and if you have dual boot , check fastboot is disabled  in windows .
- As you have problem since update, the new alsa driver may need additional parameter :
  you can try to check your codec model :
  `cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#* |grep Cod`
  Then search your codec  [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/hd-audio/models.html) or [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/tiwai/sound.git/tree/Documentation/sound/hd-audio/models.rst) and from the available models under this codec,  add line  with a similar  model to your pc at the end of  file:
  /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
  F.i. if codec is ALC898 and pc is Lenovo Yoga:
  `options snd-hda-intel model=lenovo-y530`
  Try also
  `options snd-hda-intel model=auto`

Command to check codec errors at boot:
dmesg |grep codec

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, your hint with the codec helped me (mostly because he doesn't figure on the list) to find the question / Answer which solved my problem

Comment: cool, it would be interesting  that you make answer and accept it youself , or at least give your codec name and the link  to the question/answer

Comment: uh, i didn't saw that you had already edited your question